# Solr responded with an error (HTTP 404): [Reason: HTTP Status 404 - /solr/select/] on CKAN

Tags: python, linux, solr, ckan

Lately my CKAN instance gives error 500. The CKAN error log showed below.

Solr is running but it times out when I try to access http://localhost:8983/solr

Can anyone help out.

Thanks in advance.

```
[Wed Oct 05 08:14:56.690889 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32062] 2022-10-05 08:14:56,690 ERROR [pysolr] Solr responded with an error (HTTP 404): [Reason: HTTP Status 404 - /solr/select/]
[Wed Oct 05 08:14:56.692439 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32062] 2022-10-05 08:14:56,691 ERROR [ckan.lib.search.common] Solr responded with an error (HTTP 404): [Reason: HTTP Status 404 - /solr/select/]
[Wed Oct 05 08:14:56.692465 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32062] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Oct 05 08:14:56.692475 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32062]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/search/common.py", line 57, in is_available
[Wed Oct 05 08:14:56.692485 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32062]     conn.search(q="*:*", rows=1)
[Wed Oct 05 08:14:56.692495 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32062]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 720, in search
[Wed Oct 05 08:14:56.692505 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32062]     response = self._select(params, handler=search_handler)
[Wed Oct 05 08:14:56.692515 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32062]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 418, in _select
[Wed Oct 05 08:14:56.692525 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32062]     return self._send_request('get', path)
[Wed Oct 05 08:14:56.692534 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32062]   File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 393, in _send_request
[Wed Oct 05 08:14:56.692544 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32062]     raise SolrError(error_message % (resp.status_code, solr_message))
[Wed Oct 05 08:14:56.692553 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32062] SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 404): [Reason: HTTP Status 404 - /solr/select/]
[Wed Oct 05 08:14:56.692851 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32062] 2022-10-05 08:14:56,692 WARNI [ckan.lib.search] Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server
[Wed Oct 05 08:14:57.344418 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 32062] 2022-10-05 08:14:57,344 ERROR [pysolr] Solr responded with an error (HTTP 404): [Reason: HTTP Status 404 - /solr/select/]
```

Comment: You should have a corename there as well - i.e. `/solr/corename/select` - there was some support for `/select` directly under Solr in older versions iirc, but I'm fairly certain that it was deprecated. Why ckan does this I can't really answer, but the path should include the corename.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh. Please how do I make CKAN use the corename in the path. It still times out when I access http://localhost:8983/solr/ckan

Answer (score 0):

The CKAN core dev team is residing in this Gitter chat: https://gitter.im/ckan/chat. If you ask this or other tech questions there you should get help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).